# run php script in background centos server

Tags: php, mysql, background, centos, exec

I want my php file to run in background.
When I googled, I found that `exec()` is used to run in background. I am using a CentOS server.
So, in order to use `exec`, what are all the basic things I should install?
I don't even know how to run in terminal.
What steps should I follow to run a php script in background using `exec()`?

I found this example on Google, but I don't know what to use in `$cmd`.

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nohup in your terminal:

```
nohup php my-file.php
```

Your PHP script will keep running even after you logout.

The other option is [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

```
screen -A -m -d -S whatever ./phplauncher.sh
```